# Connecting a DomainContext and loading data manually in Silverlight 4 RC application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf

I am new to WCF & RIA services and have what seems like a basic problem. I have multiple times  in my silverlight 4 RC application dragged and dropped from my datasource window to my form and have returned information from the database. However I have a need to query the database for other information (Building a report) When I try to use the following code, I recieve no error, but I also do not get any information back from the service.

```
//Global
public UMSDomainContext _umsDomainContext = new UMSDomainContext();

//In the Initialization portion
_umsDomainContext.Load(_umsDomainContext.GetUMOptionsQuery());
//Queries
 var name = from n in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                              select n.DistrictName;

                var street1 = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                              select c.Address1;

                var street2 = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                              select c.Address2;

                var city = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                              select c.City;

                var zip = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                              select c.Zip;
```

Im calling the current additional references.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using MTT.Web;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple. The data when it was being loaded in was instantly being queried. While some applications will treat this procedurally, it seems Silverlight did not wait for the data to load before moving on. So I did the following:

```
public void LoadCustomerInformation()
{
     //Load the Query
     var loadOperation = _umsDomainContext.Load<UMOption>(_umsDomainContext.GetUMOptionsQuery());
     //Create a event handler to run after the data is fully loaded.
     loadOperation.Completed += new EventHandler(loadOperation_Completed);
}

void loadOperation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var name = (from n in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                       select n.DistrictName).First();

            var street1 = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                          select c.Address1;

            var street2 = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                          select c.Address2;

            var city = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                       select c.City;

            var zip = from c in _umsDomainContext.UMOptions
                      select c.Zip;

            //Other code to work with the data, etc...
        }
```